# Without index.php in permalinks I get 404 across site

Tags: permalinks, mod-rewrite

As the title says, when I change my permalinks in the admin, all my pages return a 404 (except homepage). I have to inlclude `index.php` as the start of all the different paths. The paths all work fine, if I include `index.php`.

For example:

Custom structure: `/index.php/%postname%/%day%/` will work as I navigate my site.
Custom structure: `/%postname%/%day%/` will not work (except homepage).

mod_rewrite is enabled on the server:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
Module rewrite already enabled
```

I have a `.htaccess` file:

```
$cat /var/www/directory_name/.htaccess
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

...and it is writeable by the web server:

```
$ ls -al
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data   461 Dec  3 14:11 .htaccess
```

My apache config:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
<Directory /var/www/domain/>
    AllowOverride All
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

$cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain-ssl.conf
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` file in the document root with the appropriate mod_rewrite directives? If you do, remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper - do you get an error? IF no error, add some _nonsense_ to the start of the file - do you get an error now?

Comment: @MrWhite I've updated the question. Removing the `<IfModule>` wrapper does not produce any noticeable difference when refreshing. Adding junk doesn't do anything either. Also, my `.htaccess` is writeable by the web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Adding junk doesn't do anything either.

That suggests your `.htaccess` file is not being processed at all. You need to set `AllowOverride All` in the appropriate `<Directory>` container in the main server config (or `<VirtualHost>` container) to enable the parsing of per-directory `.htaccess` files (to *allow* `.htaccess` directives to *override* the server config).

The `FollowSymLinks` (or `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`) options also need to be enabled for mod_rewrite to function. (Although `FollowSymLinks` is enabled by default.) This can be enabled in the server config or `.htaccess` file.

For example:

```
<Directory /var/www/directory_name>
    AllowOverride All
    Options +FollowSymLinks

    # etc...    

    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Where `/var/www/directory_name` is your `DocumentRoot` and location of the `.htaccess` file.

Strictly speaking, you only *need* `AllowOverride FileInfo` to enable the use of mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`. However, you would need to enable more *groups* if you later used authorization directives, directory listings, etc.

As always, after making any changes to the server config you need to restart Apache for the changes to take effect.

> **UPDATE:** Perhaps there is an issue with my SSL conf?

Since you are redirecting *everything* to HTTPS in your server config, you need to apply the above `<Directory>` section to your `<VirtualHost *:443>` container. Applying this to `<VirtualHost *:80>` (ie. HTTP) is not required and will do nothing here.

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com [OR]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com
> RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
> ```

Your HTTP to HTTPS redirect is overly complex and can be simplified to a single mod_alias `Redirect` directive - the additional overhead of mod_rewrite is not required here.

You should also canonicalise the hostname (www or non-www) here also.

For example:

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com/
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've updated the question to include my apache config. Perhaps there is an issue with my SSL conf?

Comment: Since you are redirecting everything to HTTPS, you need to apply the above `<Directory>` section to your `<VirtualHost *:443>` container. (_Aside:_ Your HTTP to HTTPS redirect can be simplified to a mod_alias `Redirect` directive - the additional overhead of mod_rewrite is not required here.)

Comment: It was throwing 500 for everything... until I realized I left my garbage in the beginning of `.htaccess`. Thanks for your help.